How to properly setup prettier with husky and lint-staged in vue2 project?
In my Vue project, I want to run prettier on my staged files before each commit. To do this I

Installed prettier, husky and lint-staged and initialized husky with npx husky-init.
Added the following to my package.json:

  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue,css,scss,json,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }


Created a file .husky/pre-commit with the following content:

#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged

After staging a file (which I can verify with git status), I run git commit -m "test pre-commit" and get
✖ Failed to get staged files!
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)

Running npx lint-staged --debug diectly gives me
  lint-staged:bin Running `lint-staged@15.2.11` on Node.js v20.11.1 (win32) +0ms
  lint-staged:bin Options parsed from command-line: { allowEmpty: false, concurrent: true, configPath: undefined, cwd: undefined, debug: true, diff: undefined, diffFilter: undefined, maxArgLength: undefined, quiet: false, relative: false, shell: false, stash: true, hidePartiallyStaged: true, verbose: false } +1ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'version', '--build-options' ] +0ms
  lint-staged git version 2.43.0.windows.1
cpu: x86_64
built from commit: 4b968f3ea3b32a7bc50846bab49f3f381841d297
sizeof-long: 4
sizeof-size_t: 8
shell-path: /bin/sh
feature: fsmonitor--daemon +0ms
  lint-staged:validateOptions Validating options... +0ms
  lint-staged:validateOptions Validated options: { allowEmpty: false, concurrent: true, configObject: undefined, configPath: undefined, cwd: undefined, debug: true, diff: undefined, diffFilter: undefined, maxArgLength: 4095.5, quiet: false, relative: false, shell: false, stash: true, hidePartiallyStaged: true, verbose: false } +0ms
  lint-staged Unset GIT_LITERAL_PATHSPECS (was `undefined`) +2ms
  lint-staged:runAll Running all linter scripts... +0ms
  lint-staged:runAll Using working directory `C:\Users\julian.germek\Repos\aia-website` +1ms
  lint-staged:resolveGitRepo Resolving git repo from `C:\Users\julian.germek\Repos\aia-website` +0ms
  lint-staged:resolveGitRepo Unset GIT_DIR (was `undefined`) +0ms
  lint-staged:resolveGitRepo Unset GIT_WORK_TREE (was `undefined`) +0ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'rev-parse', '--show-cdup' ] +102ms
  lint-staged:resolveGitRepo Resolved git repository top-level directory to be `C:/Users/julian.germek/Repos/aia-website` +95ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'rev-parse', '--show-toplevel' ] +96ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'rev-parse', '--absolute-git-dir' ] +25ms
  lint-staged:resolveGitRepo Resolved git config directory to be `C:/Users/julian.germek/Repos/aia-website/.git` +130ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'log', '-1' ] +104ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'diff', '--name-only', '-z', '--diff-filter=ACMR', '--staged' ] +109ms
  lint-staged:execGit Running git command [ 'submodule', '--quiet', 'foreach', 'echo $displaypath' ] +106ms
✖ Failed to get staged files!

The error messages don't really help. Can you help me track down the issue and resolve it?
Thanks!

I had the same issue as you. I ran the commands manually one by one and I had an issue on this command `git submodule --quiet'. It was some subfolder with its git repo. I deleted that folder and it started working.
